# XML malformed fix using nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml

I have an xml like this but i want to convert the xml into proper xml by node.js can anyone help me in this

```
<?xml version = 1.0 encoding = utf-8?>
<!-- xslplane.1.xml -->
<?xml-stylesheet type = text/xsl  href = xslplane.1.xsl ?>
<plane>
   <year> 1977 </year>
   <make> Cessna </make>
   <model> Skyhawk </model>
   <color> Light blue and white </color>
</plane>
```

I want XML like this with all the possible quotations

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!-- xslplane.1.xml -->
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl"  href = "xslplane.1.xsl" ?>
<plane>
   <year> 1977 </year>
   <make> Cessna </make>
   <model> Skyhawk </model>
   <color> Light blue and white </color>
</plane>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to convert your malformed xml to JSON and use it again to convert to xml. Try the following code.

```
let xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = "<hi>Hello xml2js!</hi>";
xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    console.log(xml)
});
```

Update : Direct File read

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        console.log('Done');
        var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
        var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
        console.log(xml)
    });
});
```

Comment: Unquoted attribute value error as you have included the tags but no value give me an answer where the tags are like <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
and the value quotations are missing  <?xml version = 1.0 encoding = utf-8?> in the value and the o/p will be <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>

Comment: This is just a example, you can just paste your malformed xml to the xml variable, this will work

Comment: it is throwing an error Error: Unquoted attribute value

Comment: let xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = "<id nullF=UK rut=2.1.3.5/>";
xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    console.log(xml)
});

Comment: try this, it seems it does not work for self closing. let xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml =  "<id> nullF=UK rut=2.1.3.5</id>";
xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    console.log(xml)
});

Comment: The data i am expecting is from a file so i can not change the content

Comment: Try to read the file direct as in the update, I tried out with your exact xml in foo.xml and worked without an issue

Comment: It's in the answer